# How to create mathematics operations with decimal in Django - [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]

Tags: python, django, decimal

A very simple save method causes this error :

```py
class Shift(models.Model):
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    closing_type_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    closing_actual_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    diff = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    on_duty = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.diff = float(self.closing_type_amount) - float(self.closing_actual_amount)
        super(Shift, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The cause of this error is the line `self.diff = float(self.closing_type_amount) - float(self.closing_actual_amount)`
**NOTE** when give inputs more than 100 it fails ,, when a small numbers like 5, 4 , 6, 11 it works normally .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the restrictions you have set. `max_digits=4` and `decimal_places=2` allows for a maximum number of 99.99 to be saved (decimal places are included in max digits).

See usage example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DecimalField.decimal_places).

Since those are both required arguments you can set something high enough to work for most use cases. For example to store numbers up to approximately one billion with a resolution of 10 decimal places:

```
models.DecimalField(..., max_digits=19, decimal_places=10)
```

I would also suggest a bit of a change to your model because in my opinion saving the `diff` value is redundant since you already have the two values you calculate it from. Rather add a property to your model to calculate it on the fly:

```
class Shift(models.Model):
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    closing_type_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    closing_actual_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    on_duty = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    @property
    def diff(self):
        return float(self.closing_type_amount) - float(self.closing_actual_amount)
```

Also, if you are going to cast to `float` you might as well use [FloatField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#floatfield) instead of DecimalField.